# For a n x n matrix A that is a product of elementary matrices, the null space of A is the zero subspace null(A) = {0}

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been trying to reason why this statement is true or false. From what I understand, the nullspace(A) is the set of column vectors where Ax = 0 and that an n x n matrix must be a square matrix.

The question I had asked myself is the connection between nxn matrix A being a product of elementary matrices and when the nullspace of a matrix has only the trivial solution making nullspace(A) the zerosubspace.

Help on connecting these ideas?

Comment: What is the definition of an "elementary matrix"?

Comment: This follows from the definition of an [elemenatry matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix). It is invertible, so that $A$ is also invertible, and hence has trivial nullspace.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is the product of elementary matrices if and only if $A$ is invertible, which is equivalent to its null space being trivial.

First, if $A$ is the product of elementary matrices then it is invertible as the product of invertible matrices (all elementary matrices are invertible).

On the other hand, if $A$ is invertible, then it is row equivalent to the unit matrix. Meaning, there is a sequence of elementary matrices $E_1,...,E_k$ (which correspond to the appropriate elementary row operations) such that:
$$E_K...E_1A=I\Rightarrow A=(E_1)^{-1}...(E_k)^{-1}$$
Since the inverse of an elementary matrix is also an elementary matrix, we see that $A$ is the product of elementary matrices.

Why is being invertible equivalent to the null space being trivial? Since the null space of $A$ is trivial if and only if its row reduced Echelon form is the unit matrix (this can be seen by considering the homogeneous system $Ax=0$), which brings us back to $A$ being invertible.

Comment: Thank you ! I understand the connection now